# detecting zombie processes

Tags: linux

how do I detect and kill zombie processes left from the command line of a Linux terminal?

Comment: You can't kill the undead :P. Zombie process are dead process that are waiting to be "waited" with the parent process. In this process the parent knows how their children ended. When ever the terminal ends, this process will be inherit by init and init will "wait" them. So what you need is to kill/end the parent process.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot kill a zombie process. If the parent process does not call `wait()`, you have to kill the parent process to remove the zombie.

Answer (score 1):

You can grep for "defunct", or check for `Z` in the "state" output

```
ps -eo state,pid,cmd | grep "^Z"
```

If you want to kill it as well

```
ps -eo state,ppid | awk '$1=="Z"{cmd="kill -9 "$2;system(cmd) }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ps aux
```

and look at the status column. Zombie are represented by letter Z.

Answer (score -1):

try ps ax -o state -o ppid  | awk '$1=="Z"{print $2}' | xargs kills all zombies

Comment: Can you expand your answer a little to explain what the code does?  (I'm envisioning that maybe the ax is used to cut off their heads?  :-)    )

Comment: While this command may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Comment: This is formatted poorly so that the command and descriptive text overlap.  Also, even if corrected, this won't work for parent processes that trap SIGTERM.